# Formula count days after today?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create domain remember in MS excel, how do i count the day until my domain is expired?

```
 Expired Date | Expired In Day(s)
 10/27/2012   | ???
 11/27/2011   | ???
 12/6/2011    | ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `=A2-TODAY()` like shown [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-days-before-a-date-HP003056153.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If your exp date is in cell a2 `=int(a2-now())`.  This works, because excel internally saves date/time as date as whole number counting from somewhere beginning of 20th century, then below decimal representing fraction of day (e.g 0.5 is noon, 0.25 is 6am).  so the formula throw away time less than one and then report days.